# “The given path's format is not supported.”

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to create a PDF via C# using iTextSharp

```
if (emp.FormDesc == "FormOne")
   {
      string filePath = @"\\G:\SharedDrive\Forms\FormOne\" + filename;

       // Write out PDF from memory stream.
       using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath))
        {
           fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
        }
    }
```

I am returning this string

```
filePath = "\\\\G:\\SharedDrive\\Forms\\FormOne\\11-23-2020.pdf"
```

but I keep getting the error message “The given path's format is not supported.”

Any ideas? My syntax seems correct.

Thank you.

Comment: `\\G:\ ` doesn't look like a proper path. It should be either a local drive (`G:`) or a network path `\\ `. Have a path that works in your explorer, and then use that in your code.

Comment: @Michael you still shouldn't use "\\" in front of a drive letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
string filePath = @"\\G:\SharedDrive\Forms\FormOne\" + filename;
```

To this:

```
string filePath = @"G:\SharedDrive\Forms\FormOne\" + filename;
```

Or if it is a network share, then something like this:

```
string filePath = @"\\SharedDrive\Forms\FormOne\" + filename;
```

where "SharedDrive" is the name of the network share.

(edited in response to first comment below)

Comment: How do you know it's not `\\SharedDrive\Forms\FormOne`?

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about a network drive, but I will update the answer just in case...

Comment: Didn't mention local drive either, but for a reason used `\\ `, so it's definitely not clear.

Comment: @JesseChunn Yes, I forgot to mention it was a network drive

Comment: Technically, if it is a "network drive", i.e. a network location that is mapped to a drive letter, then you do not want the "\\" in front of the path, you just want the drive letter. If, on the other hand, you are trying to access a network location, you should use the "UNC" path convention, like "\\SharedDrive\...". Still not sure which @MichaelMaslova was looking to do.

Comment: @JesseChunn as stated above in my comment above, I forgot to mention it was for a network drive. you have covered all your bases though. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The better and saffer way is using `Path.Combine` like below:

```
 string filePath = Path.Combine("G:\SharedDrive\Forms\FormOne", filename);
```